# How I can make a custom clickeable area?

Tags: android

how I can make a custom clickeable area/button? For example, If I have a semicircle as the image below, how I can make the whole area red, blue or gray are clickable and independent?

[image]

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: You can set button as a Transparent and trigger onClick event.

Comment: set the Whole view as one, and calculate in the onTouchlistener the are which was clicked by coordinates

Comment: PiYusH GuPtA if you see the image, it is not rectangular, with a button I can't include the entire area.

A.S. I don't have idea how to do it, Is it difficult? Do you have any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this example :

https://mega.co.nz/#%21lMUHQTAQ%21Tr3i-3iYnsNt8-2DshNbwBAObJkZFU7NJGYMu5RBxGw

[image]

Or :
https://mega.co.nz/#!0M9HUTKZ!cMe8iDz4BnV5aPc92eIRTG8JHqMHSntSUi_0YelfU7M

[image]

Comment: So much thanks, this look awesome. You are my god. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned – make the whole view as one, and calculate in the onTouchlistener().
I would transform the touch coordinates in [polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) (polar angle, radial distance).

Then just check if the radial distance is between inner circle and outer circle radius. If it is, then some button was clicked. You can determine which button was clicked from polar angle (e.g. 0-120 degrees = red button, 120-240 degrees = gray button, 240-360= blue button).